# Merge 2 Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, magento, soap

I am working on formatting an array for a Magento soap call.  I have two mysql queries and ARRAY1 and ARRAY2 are the results. How would I merge/combine ARRAY1 and ARRAY2 so that the results are like ARRAY3?

I appreciate any help.

ARRAY1

```
<pre>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "store1"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "product1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "store1"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "product2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "store2"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "product2"
  }
}
</pre>
```

ARRAY2

```
<pre>
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["status"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["status"]=>
    string(2) "No"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["status"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
}
</pre>
```

ARRAY3

```
<pre>
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'store1' (length=6)
      1 => string 'product1' (length=8)
      2 => 
          array (size=1)
           'status' => string 'Yes' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'store1' (length=6)
      1 => string 'product2' (length=8)
      2 => 
          array (size=1)
           'status' => string 'No' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'store2' (length=6)
      1 => string 'product2' (length=8)
      2 => 
          array (size=1)
           'status' => string 'No' (length=2)
</pre>
```

Comment: Would [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge-recursive.php) help here?

Comment: There is no `store3` or `product3` in arrays 1 or 2 - but it showed up in array 3. Please revise your data or clarify your question.

Comment: why not do a database table join if there is a relationship between those 2 arrays? are they coming from different sources?

Comment: Yannick - The queries are coming from the same table.  I would like to do a join but I was getting hung up because I was using 'mysqli_fetch_array' on one of the queries and 'mysqli_fetch_assoc' on the other.

Comment: Mark M - Fixed the typos in the arrays.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two arrays are lined up perfectly, this may help:

```
<?php
$i = 0; 
foreach ($array1 as $item) {
array_push($item, $array2[$i]);
$i++;
} 
?>
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for.  Doing some testing now.